# "call 'refresh'" error resulting from Grails WAR hot-deploy

Tags: grails

When my Grails WAR is hot-deployed to Tomcat and I refresh the page, I get this error:

> 1 Feb, 2010 7:00:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet view-servlet threw exception
>   **java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext**
>    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:15

This error does not persist when Tomcat is restarted.

Comment: Can't help you with the servlet error, but I can tell you it doesn't have anything to do with the Javascript in your page. Something is wrong in Java land.

Comment: there should be another stacktrace preceding this one

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();

Spring try to lookup the applicationContext.xml from the CLASSPATH, if the xml file can't be found, "BeanFactory not initialized or already closed" error will be thrown out. That is why you restart the tomcat it works just fine. However I don't know the real cause why the applicationContext.xml is not in the classpath during hot-deploy.

If you are running only one Grails application in your tomcat, you can try to put the applicationContext.xml in Tomcat classpath and try hot-deploy again.