# How can I cope with "IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed"?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, groovy, tomcat7

With Grails 2.0.0 on Tomcat 7 I get the following right at startup:

```
2011-08-21 11:10:09,758 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.containsBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader$1.run(GrailsContextLoader.java:88)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.lifecycle.ShutdownOperations.runOperations(ShutdownOperations.java:62)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4763)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.run(StandardContext.java:5472)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
2011-08-21 11:10:09,761 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**What could the cause of this be? How can it be resolved?**

*NOTE: If you know the solution you may also be able to answer ["call 'refresh'" error resulting from Grails WAR hot-deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177563/grails-call-refresh-error) as posted by a different user.*

Comment: there should be another trace preceding this one

Comment: It's actually the entire logfile ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turned out there was additional info provided in the logfile `catalina.out`. I had only checked the application specific `stacktrace.log` when I posted the question.

*Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho for the hint on that!*

The problem stemmed from the application being unable to connect to the database.

**Thus it could be resolved by configuring access privileges on the database side.**

Comment: Thanks, mine ended up being caused by bad spring security config but this helped me track it down.